# UIButton click, while NIB is loaded from other XIB file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a View (called MyView) in my Layout file. I want to content to be loaded from another XIB file (called FooterView). This works fine, this way:

```
NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FooterView" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *footerView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
[MyView addSubview:footerView];
```

But what if I have a button in my FooterView, with the *Touch Up Inside* linked to a IBAction in my FooterView.m class? 
At the moment, when I click on the button, I'm receiving this error:
*unrecognized selector sent to instance*

It would be great if I can catch the button click in the FooterView.m class.
How can I get this done?

Edit: I now have the following problem: I want to change the view from My FooterView class (which inherits from UIView) like this:

```
NewView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:distilleryView animated:YES];
```

Where NewView is a UIViewController. I can't call presentModalViewController from a View. I also tried getting the parentclass from self, but that doesn't work either.

How can I make this work?

Comment: have you define the IBAction method in your FooterView.m?

Comment: @MuditBajpai I did, I have an IBAction in my .h and .m file, and connected this one using the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to set the file's owner to 
FooterView in xib like this one

[image]

Comment: One doubt: how he can give `footerViewObj` as owner when he is getting `UIView *footerViewObj = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];` after that initialization of `subviewArray`

Comment: yesh Adil you are right I just got confused... now edited my answer again

Comment: It doesn't work when I set the Custom Class to FooterView, still receiving the same error. It does work though when I do it like your unedited comment:     `FooterView *fv = [[FooterView alloc] init];
    
    NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FooterView" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *footerView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
    [currentFooter addSubview:footerView];`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I made an edit to my first post. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it making a custom constructor, that needs the UIViewController. I save the UIViewController in the FooterView class as `UIViewController *parent`. Right now, I can say  `[parent presentModalViewController:distilleryView animated:YES];`